# Slack slackv2 Version

Tags: slack

i need to install slack in my org but i can't find the lastest version.
this is the namespace prefix version: Slackv2.
i only can find this :
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFo7gUAD&_ga=2.138083760.1411698130.1702910942-658775869.1697045768

Answer (score 0):

Do not use that package. It is a non-secure and no-longer supported package.

Use the native Slack integrations provided by Salesforce.